# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() even after calling Read()

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I'm having this weird error, which doesn't compare to any of the errors in the other questions.
I'm pretty sure that i'm doing it correctly, but keeps giving me this error.
Heres my code:

```
myconn.Open();
            Bidreader = command.ExecuteReader();


            Maxbids.Clear();
            bidders.Clear();
            Minbids.Clear();
            Bidreader.Read();
            Maxbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Bidreader["Maxbid"].ToString()));
            Minbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Bidreader["Minbid"].ToString()));
            bidders.Add(Bidreader["Name"].ToString());
            Bidreader.Read();
            Maxbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Bidreader["Maxbid"].ToString()));
            Minbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Bidreader["Minbid"].ToString()));
            bidders.Add(Bidreader["Name"].ToString());
            Bidreader.Close();

            Bidreader.Close();
            myconn.Close();
```

The error i'm getting is this:
Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

Ohh and i forgot to write that this code is in a timer_tick.

UPDATE !!:
Now i've rewritten it, with the help from you guys:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    string Currentitem;
    int Timeleftint;
    int Highestbid = 0;
    int WinnerBid;
    int Givenitems;
    List<int> Maxbids = new List<int>();
    List<int> Minbids = new List<int>();
    List<string> bidders = new List<string>();
    string Highestbidder = "None";
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer Itemtimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer Bidcheck = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }


private void Bidcheck_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConnection = "";
        MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
        MySqlCommand command = myconn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Name,MinBid,MaxBid,Item FROM bids WHERE Item ='" + Currentitem + "' ORDER BY MaxBid DESC";

            myconn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader Bidreader = command.ExecuteReader();              
            Maxbids.Clear();
            bidders.Clear();
            Minbids.Clear();

            Bidreader.Read();
            while (Bidreader.Read())
            {
                Maxbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Bidreader["Maxbid"].ToString()));
                Minbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Bidreader["Minbid"].ToString()));
                bidders.Add(Bidreader["Name"].ToString());
               }
            MessageBox.Show(bidders[0] + Maxbids[0] + Minbids[0]);
            MessageBox.Show(bidders[1] + Maxbids[1] + Minbids[1]);

            Bidreader.Close();
            myconn.Close();
```

Now i'm getting a new error, which is almost even weirder.
Even though i do the Bidreader.Read() I still get an error because Maxbids, Minbids and bidders doesn't have any indexes when trying to show it in messagebox. I guess this means that this means that it never reads the data.
Am i right?

Comment: you are closing it twice..

Comment: You should check what the method `Read()` returns. Perhaps there are no rows in your dataset, so the `DbDataReader` cannot obtain any rows.

Comment: you're also calling Bidreader twice, remove the second one. Use a while loop to read your data

Comment: `"SELECT Name,MinBid,MaxBid,Item FROM bids WHERE Item ='" + Currentitem + "' ORDER BY MaxBid DESC"` Currentitem has no value in  your method, that would be your problem

Comment: Omg sorry, im so dumb...
It must be the hours of coding, which is messing with my head :D

Comment: also remove `Bitreader.Read();` above the while loop, you don't need it it's being done on the next line in the while.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not using SqlDataReader then change that to what ever you're using. Wrap your connection in a using statement, add your command then put this code inside of it.

[**Source Example: MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

```
    SqlDataReader bidReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (bidReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (bidReader.Read())
        {
            Maxbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(bidReader["Maxbid"].ToString()));
            Minbids.Add(Convert.ToInt16(bidReader["Minbid"].ToString()));
            bidders.Add(bidReader["Name"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: show all your code, even when you initialize max,min and bidders. Even your command properties. It's not getting any results from the query.

Comment: This is all i can share, since i have a lot of database info.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening ?